# Ошибка при парсинге python: IndentationError: expected an indented block

Tags: python, парсер

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import re


def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    # return html code of URL
    return r.text


def get_total_pages(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    pages = soup.find('div', class_='ui-pagination').find_all('a', class_='page-next ui-pagination-next')[-1]
    total_pages = pages.split('/')[5].split('.')[0]
    return int(total_pages)


def get_page_data():


def main():
    url = 'https://ru.aliexpress.com/af/flash%252B32%252Bgb/3.html?isAffiliate=y&initiative_id=AS_20170204114829&site=rus&SearchText=flash+32+gb&tc=af&CatId=202001176'
    base_url = 'https://ru.aliexpress.com/af/flash%252B32%252Bgb/'
    dynamic_part = ''
    query_part = '.html?isAffiliate=y&initiative_id=AS_20170204114829&site=rus&SearchText=flash+32+gb&tc=af&CatId=202001176'
    total_pages = get_total_pages(get_html(url))

    for i in range(1,3):
        url_gen= base_url + dynamic_part + str(i) + query_part
            print(url_gen)


if __name__ == ' __main__ ':
    main()
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
File "newparse.py", line 35
    def main():
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: print(url_gen) - отступ сравняйте с предыдущей строкой

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

У вас же функция get_page_data пустая. Поэтому он и ругается на строку с заголовком следующей функции - он-то ожидал сначала увидеть содержимое этой функции.

Ну и как вам сказали в комментариях, есть ещё одна ошибка, хоть и не связанная с вашей проблемой.